# IBMRestServlet vs ServletContainer

Tags: rest, websphere

What are the advantages that offer implement REST WS with IBMRestServlet over ServletContainer?

I noted that the servlets have different configuration on web.xml:

For  ServletContainer:
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

And IBM implementation:
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JAXRS</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.myapp.ServiceApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
I'm using a Websphere 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to deploy Jersey for the former to work, don't you? The latter is part of WebSphere and officially supported under WebSphere (meaning you can get IBM support if you have problems with it).

(A quick web search does show at least a few hits on quirks or difficulties with Jersey under some versions of WebSphere, some of them even right here on StackOverflow.)